# how to redirect with jquery a page to another when a counter ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hello programmers this is my question today, what function in jquery do i need so when a counter reach the number 100 that page is redirected to the main menu?

Comment: You don't *need* any jQuery function at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check the counter's value with an if statement and if the value is 100, then simply:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

There is no need for JQuery in this.